# rendering part of Images to screen from DB - react native

Tags: image, react-native

I am creating an app in react native, which has a few screens. in one of the screens, I would like to show images that I get from DB (I Get from DB 20 uri images addresses, and want to render randomly 6 on the screen at a time).
when the user touch one of the images, it goes to carrousel which has all the images that the user press on. each image that the user pressed, switch to another image that not been showed yet.

I have tried to use FlatList, but it forced me to render all the images once, and as I said, I want to render 6 at a time.

any help? suggestions?

Comment: If you want to show only 6 images at a time, you can simply use 6 `<Image />` component and set them into `<ScrollView />` then you can put this logic. Also, I'm suggesting you use `FastImage` library, while you're using so many Image logic.

Comment: thx for the comment. but how can i pass the id, or others details of one image when pressed? imagine that I want to delete image, or do with it something, how can I pass to the touchable opacity that surrounding the image some id or others details?

Comment: You can create a map to store the image and its detail. In the onPress function, you already know which one is pressed and put it into the logic

Comment: you can give me an example of syntax?

Comment: Sure, wait a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example App.js

```
import React from "react";
import {
  Image,
  StatusBar,
  ScrollView,
  SafeAreaView,
  TouchableOpacity
} from "react-native";

const staticData = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: "test",
    uri:
      "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1586687803268-e400f13af4db?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: "test",
    uri:
      "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1586687803268-e400f13af4db?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    title: "test",
    uri:
      "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1586687803268-e400f13af4db?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80"
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    title: "test",
    uri:
      "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1586687803268-e400f13af4db?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80"
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    title: "test",
    uri:
      "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1586687803268-e400f13af4db?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80"
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    title: "test",
    uri:
      "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1586687803268-e400f13af4db?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80"
  }
];

const App = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <StatusBar barStyle="dark-content" />
      <SafeAreaView>
        <ScrollView
          horizontal
          contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior="automatic"
          style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: "center", justifyContent: "center" }}
        >
          {staticData.map(item => {
            const { id, title, uri } = item;
            return (
              <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={() => {
                  // Magic logic here
                  // Selected one's data is 'item'
                }}
              >
                <Image style={{ height: 150, width: 150 }} source={{uri: uri}} />
              </TouchableOpacity>
            );
          })}
        </ScrollView>
      </SafeAreaView>
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```